# Backtester Written in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, finance

I am writing a code for backtesting share prices, initial coding had some errors which i figured out with the help of SO members. Now the code is in final stage. and i have added various functionalities in the back testing. The program perform following steps :

1. Read values from txt file
2. store data into array
3. calculate moving average (for a range of values) in 2D array mag[][]
4. point every trade where there is a cross over of MA with price (basic MA crossover rule in stock market).
5. make a list of trades.
6. provide a summary for all the values (range) test.

Everything seems to be working fine. All values are printing when they are in the main file... but after finishing the code, just to crosscheck i tried to read the array values at the end of program again.. this time it is showing some garbage instead of real values.

Following is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX_FILE_NAME 100
#define MAXCHAR 1000
int main()
{
FILE *fp;
int count=0,k1=0,k2=0,k=0;
char filename[MAX_FILE_NAME];
char c; // To store a character read from file

// Get file name from user. The file should be
// either in current folder or complete path should be provided
printf("Enter file name or full path: ");
scanf("%s", filename);
printf("Enter the minimum rolling period for calculation : \n");
scanf("%d", &k1);
printf("Enter the maximum rolling period for calculation : \n");
scanf("%d", &k2);
// Open the file

fp = fopen(filename, "r");

// Check if file exists
if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not open file %s", filename);
    return 0;
}

// Extract characters from file and store in character c
for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp))
    if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline
        count = count + 1;
// Close the file
fclose(fp);
//printf("The file %s has %d lines\n", filename, count);
FILE *myFile;
myFile = fopen(filename, "r");
//read file into array
float numberArray[count];
int i;
if (myFile == NULL)
{
    printf("Error Reading File\n");
    exit (0);
}
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    fscanf(myFile, "%f,", &numberArray[i]);
}

fclose(myFile);
float data[count],mag[k2+1][count];
int buy[k2+1][count],sell[k2+1][count];
int ftrade[k2+1],fbtrade[k2+1],fstrade[k2+1],ltrade[k2+1];
for (k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    double avg=0,sum=0;
    for (i=0; i<k-1; i++)
    {
        mag[k][i-1]=0;
        sum=sum+numberArray[i];
    }
    for(i=k-1; i<=count; i++)
    {
        mag[k][i-1]=avg;
        sum=sum+numberArray[i]-numberArray[i-k];
        avg = sum/k;
    }
}

for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{

    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if((numberArray[i]<mag[k][i]) && (numberArray[i+1]>mag[k][i+1]))
            buy[k][i+1]=1;
        else
            buy[k][i+1]=0;
    }
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if((numberArray[i]>mag[k][i]) && (numberArray[i+1]<mag[k][i+1]))
            sell[k][i+1]=-1;
        else
            sell[k][i+1]=0;
    }
}

for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if(buy[k][i]==1 || sell[k][i]==-1)
        {
            ftrade[k]=i;
            break;
        }
    }
}

for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if(buy[k][i]==1)
        {
            fbtrade[k]=i;
            break;
        }
    }
}

for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{

    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if(sell[k][i]==-1)
        {
            fstrade[k]=i;
            break;
        }
    }
}

for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if(buy[k][i]==1 || sell[k][i]==-1)
        {
            ltrade[k]=i;
        }
    }
}


for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    printf("\nFirst Trade for %d =  %d",k,ftrade[k]);
    printf("\nFirst Buy Trade for %d =  %d",k,fbtrade[k]);
    printf("\nFirst Sell Trade for %d =  %d",k,fstrade[k]);
    printf("\nLast Trade for %d =  %d",k,ltrade[k]);
}


/**************************************
STEP - 8 : Count the number of trades (Buy & SELL)
************************************************/
int btradesarray[k2],stradesarray[k2];
for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    btradesarray[k]=0,stradesarray[k]=0;
    int btrades=0,strades=0;
    for(i=0; i<=count; i++)
    {
        if(buy[k][i]==1)
        {
            btrades=btrades+1;
            btradesarray[k]=btrades;
        }
        else if(sell[k][i]==-1)
        {
            strades=strades+1;
            stradesarray[k]=strades;
        }
    }
}

for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    printf("\nTotal Buy Trades for %d is = %d",k,btradesarray[k]);
}

/**************************************
STEP - 9 : TOTAL TRADES
************************************************/

int ttrades[k2];
for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    ttrades[k]=btradesarray[k]+stradesarray[k]-1;
}

for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    printf("\nTotal Trades for %d is = %d",k,ttrades[k]);
}

/**************************************
STEP - 9 : Making Trade List and profit calculation
************************************************/
float tradelist[k2][count];
float profit[k2][count];
int j=0;
for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    for(i=ftrade[k]; i<count; i++)
    {

        if(buy[i]!=0)
        {
            tradelist[k][j]= numberArray[i];
            j++;
        }
        else if (sell[i]!=0)
        {
            tradelist[k][j]= -1*numberArray[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
}

printf("\n+++++++++++++   CHECKING    ++++++++++++++++");
for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    printf("\nTotal Trades for %d is = %d",k,ttrades[k]);
    printf("\nTotal Buy Trades for %d is = %d",k,btradesarray[k]);
}
}
```

In checking section it is printing garbage of same variable which it is printing correctly during the program run.

Following is the output :

[image]

Comment: Given a declaration like `int ttrades[k2]`, you aren't allowed to have a loop like `for(k=k1;k<=k2;k++)`. That's because the indexes into `ttrade` are 0 to `k2-1`. So when `k` is equal to `k2`, you are writing past the end of the array.

Comment: Seems you have some memory overwrite in step 9 which destroys `ttrades`. Try to print `k` and `i` in step 9. My guess is that `ftrade[k]` gives you an unexpected value

Comment: @user3386109 i have modified all declaration of k2 to k2+1. But it has not effect on output.

Comment: @4386427 There is no memory overwrite in step 9. i have double checked it.

Comment: @MohdNaved As there is no answers yet you should edit the code in the question

Comment: I'm sure that there are other off-by-one errors in the code. You need to find and fix all of them.

Comment: As the last thing you do in step 8 is the same as you do in the ckecking, the only explanation is memory overwrite in step 9.

Comment: I have updated the code.. after implement the comment of @user3386109, but there is not change in the result.

Comment: @MohdNaved Try this in step 9: `if(buy[i]!=0)` ==> `printf("i=%d j=%d\n", i, j); if(buy[i]!=0)` and show us the output. My guess is that `j` is larger than allowed

Comment: @4386427, i added the code.. and as output its showing i=165, j=825.

Comment: Isn't that overwriting memory when you do `tradelist[k][j]` ? What is the value of `count`? Is that more than 825?

Comment: count is correct as it should be 165. but j is not correct as it should be the number of trades ( different values for different k).. value should be equal to total trades for each value of k.

Comment: So there **is** a memory overwrite in step 9. I'm not sure what you are trying in step 9. Maybe you need to reset `j` to zero before the inner loop ? I don't know. What you can do is "printf debug" - that is ... add print statements in step 9 to see exactly the values used for indexing.

Answer (score 1):

finally i did it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX_FILE_NAME 100
#define MAXCHAR 1000
int main()
{
FILE *fp;
int count=0,k1=0,k2=0,k=0;
char filename[MAX_FILE_NAME];
char c; // To store a character read from file

// Get file name from user. The file should be
// either in current folder or complete path should be provided
printf("Enter file name or full path: ");
scanf("%s", filename);
printf("Enter the minimum rolling period for calculation : \n");
scanf("%d", &k1);
printf("Enter the maximum rolling period for calculation : \n");
scanf("%d", &k2);
// Open the file

fp = fopen(filename, "r");

// Check if file exists
if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not open file %s", filename);
    return 0;
}

// Extract characters from file and store in character c
for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp))
    if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline
        count = count + 1;
// Close the file
fclose(fp);
//printf("The file %s has %d lines\n", filename, count);
FILE *myFile;
myFile = fopen(filename, "r");
//read file into array
float numberArray[count];
int i;
if (myFile == NULL)
{
    printf("Error Reading File\n");
    exit (0);
}
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    fscanf(myFile, "%f,", &numberArray[i]);
}

fclose(myFile);
float data[count],mag[k2+1][count];
int buy[k2+1][count],sell[k2+1][count];
int ftrade[k2+1],fbtrade[k2+1],fstrade[k2+1],ltrade[k2+1];
for (k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    double avg=0,sum=0;
    for (i=0; i<k-1; i++)
    {
        mag[k][i-1]=0;
        sum=sum+numberArray[i];
    }
    for(i=k-1; i<=count; i++)
    {
        mag[k][i-1]=avg;
        sum=sum+numberArray[i]-numberArray[i-k];
        avg = sum/k;
    }
}

for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{

    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if((numberArray[i]<mag[k][i]) && (numberArray[i+1]>mag[k][i+1]))
            buy[k][i+1]=1;
        else
            buy[k][i+1]=0;
    }
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if((numberArray[i]>mag[k][i]) && (numberArray[i+1]<mag[k][i+1]))
            sell[k][i+1]=-1;
        else
            sell[k][i+1]=0;
    }
}

for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if(buy[k][i]==1 || sell[k][i]==-1)
        {
            ftrade[k]=i;
            break;
        }
    }
}

for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if(buy[k][i]==1)
        {
            fbtrade[k]=i;
            break;
        }
    }
}

for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{

    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if(sell[k][i]==-1)
        {
            fstrade[k]=i;
            break;
        }
    }
}

for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if(buy[k][i]==1 || sell[k][i]==-1)
        {
            ltrade[k]=i;
        }
    }
}


for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    printf("\nFirst Trade for %d =  %d",k,ftrade[k]);
    printf("\nFirst Buy Trade for %d =  %d",k,fbtrade[k]);
    printf("\nFirst Sell Trade for %d =  %d",k,fstrade[k]);
    printf("\nLast Trade for %d =  %d",k,ltrade[k]);
}


/**************************************
STEP - 8 : Count the number of trades (Buy & SELL)
************************************************/
int btradesarray[k2],stradesarray[k2];
for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    btradesarray[k]=0,stradesarray[k]=0;
    int btrades=0,strades=0;
    for(i=0; i<=count; i++)
    {
        if(buy[k][i]==1)
        {
            btrades=btrades+1;
            btradesarray[k]=btrades;
        }
        else if(sell[k][i]==-1)
        {
            strades=strades+1;
            stradesarray[k]=strades;
        }
    }
}

for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    printf("\nTotal Buy Trades for %d is = %d",k,btradesarray[k]);
}

/**************************************
STEP - 9 : TOTAL TRADES
************************************************/

int ttrades[k2];
for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    ttrades[k]=btradesarray[k]+stradesarray[k]-1;
}

for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    printf("\nTotal Trades for %d is = %d",k,ttrades[k]);
}

/**************************************
STEP - 9 : Making Trade List and profit calculation
************************************************/
float tradelist[k2+1][count];
float profit[k2+1][count];
int j;
for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    for(i=ftrade[k]; i<count; i++)
    {
        if(buy[k][i]==1)
        {
            tradelist[k][j]= numberArray[i];
        }
        else if (sell[k][i]==-1)
        {
            tradelist[k][j]= -1*numberArray[i];
        }
        j++;
    }
    if(j>=count)
    {
        j=0;
    }

    printf("\nThe value of J = %d",j);
}



printf("\n+++++++++++++   CHECKING    ++++++++++++++++");
for(k=k1; k<=k2; k++)
{
    printf("\nTotal Trades for %d is = %d",k,ttrades[k]);
    printf("\nTotal Buy Trades for %d is = %d",k,btradesarray[k]);
}
}
```

Here is the result output:

[image]

Comment: Sorry to be the one to give you the bad news, but you still have several errors in the code. C does not have any built-in protection against out-of-bounds array access. So it's up to the programmer to get it right. That means that if you have an array with `N` elements, the code must only access the array with indexes between `0` and `N-1`. Accessing with a negative index, or an index greater than or equal to `N` results in undefined behavior. And your code still does both, it accesses arrays with negative indexes and indexes beyond the end of the array.

Comment: @user3386109 : Kindly let me know where it is accessing negative index or or greater index than assigned.. so that i can rectify the code. Thanks in advance for the help.